# Error in http connection org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, json, mobile, http

Quando tento pegar um `JSONArray` da internet, ele apresenta um erro.

## Erro

`Error in http connection org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`

Este erro acontece quando ele vai tentar ler a resposta da internet. Ele interrompe o doInBackground e vai direto pro onPostExecute...

## JSON que o link retorna:

```
[{"id":"2","data":"03\/06\/2016 11:11:20","texto":"Mande suas mensagens","nome":null},{"id":"1","data":"02\/06\/2016 11:28:10","texto":"Bom dia!","nome":null}]
```

## Código:

```
public void carregaMural(View v){ new LongOperation2().execute("");}
private class LongOperation2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressBar carrega = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.carregaMsg);
    public char getChar(char x){return x;}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            verifica = '0';  //SE FOR INTERROMPIDO, TENTA NOVAMENTE. . .                
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.siteteste.com.br/app/listener.php?a=10");
            httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            resultRecebe = sb.toString();
            is.close();
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            Log.v("JSON", jsonArray.toString());
            verifica = '1';
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in SocketException "
                    + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "
                    + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        carrega.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(verifica == '0'){//FOI INTERROMPIDO?
            new LongOperation2().execute(""); //TENTA NOVAMENTE
        }else{
            mandaLista();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        carrega.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Comment: No seu doInbackground em vez de colocar return null, coloque return verifica. E coloque verifica = '0', antes do try{}.

Comment: Tente usar GET ao invés do seu POST, você tá indo buscar URL

Comment: Será que o erro não ocorre quando tenta transformar em JSON ? o erro ocorre em **org.json.JSONException** !!! Poderia colocar o erro inteiro? Aí falicita na solução! Obrigado!

Comment: É verdade, o listener.php está retornando com json_encode()?

Comment: Colocando o GET no lugar do POST ele parou de dar o erro, depois ele começou a dar null pointer exception mas, isso foi devido a um erro de sintaxe mesmo. JSONArray estava recebendo a variavel result sendo que era pra receber a resultRecebe. Agora esta funcionando bem. Obrigado :))